# MultiScript Bibliography using biber/xelatex/polyglossia

Tags: xetex, biber, polyglossia

I have succeeded in having a multiscript document using polyglossia. I tried to use biber to have a multiscript bibliography. Every thing compiles well but the Arabic Script in the .bib file doesn't print in the pdf file. It appears correctly in the TexWorks log but doesn't appear at all int he pdf file, with no related warning in the log, and even after forcing utf-8 encoding.

Here is the Minimal code:

in main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=3]{Arabic Typesetting}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References/newref.bib}
```

in newref.bib

```
@article{arabic1,
author ={عزيزة مبارك العلوني, مريم عبد الرحمن السهلي, مهرة فارس المطيري, ندى محمد ميمني},
journal = {رسالة ماجستير غير منشورة},
title = {برنامج تعليمي الكتروني في تنمية بعض من مهارات الاستعداد للقراءة لدى  أطفال ما قبل المدرسة},
url = {http://www.minshawi.com/node/2241},
year = 2011
}
```

**Update:** here is the log:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Biber reported the following issues
(biblatex)                with 'arabic1':
(biblatex)                - Name "ط¹ط²ظٹط²ط© ظ…ط¨ط§ط±ظƒ ط§ظ„ط¹ظ„ظˆظ†ظٹ, ظ…ط±ظٹظ
… ط¹ط¨ط¯ ط§ظ„ط±ط­ظ…ظ† ط§ظ„ط³ظ‡ظ„ظٹ, ظ…ظ‡ط±ط© ظپط§ط±ط³ ط§ظ„ظ…ط·ظٹط±ظٹ, ظ†ط¯ظ‰ ظ…
ط­ظ…ط¯ ظ…ظٹظ…ظ†ظٹ" has too many commas: skipping name.

)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 74.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 74.
Requested font "[lmsans12-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 12.0pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans12-regular.otf
Requested font "[lmsans10-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.95pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-regular.otf
Requested font "[lmsans10-bold]:mapping=tex-text" at 12.0pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf
File: TitlePage/GUC-logo-ss.ps Graphic file (type eps)
 <TitlePage/GUC-logo-ss.ps>
Requested font "[lmsans17-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 17.28pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans17-regular.otf
File: TitlePage/logo2.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <TitlePage/logo2.eps>
Requested font "[lmsans10-bold]:mapping=tex-text" at 17.28pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf

Overfull \vbox (91.82722pt too high) detected at line 83
 []

Requested font "[lmsans10-bold]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.95pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf
Requested font "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.95pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
[1

] [1

] ("E:\Lolla\My Work\Masters\Thesis files\Thesis\main.toc"
Requested font "[lmroman12-bold]:mapping=tex-text" at 12.0pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-bold.otf
Requested font "[lmroman8-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 8.0pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman8-regular.otf
Requested font "[lmroman6-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 6.0pt
 -> C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman6-regular.otf
Requested font "cmmi12" at 12.0pt
 -> cmmi12
Requested font "cmmi8" at 8.0pt
 -> cmmi8
Requested font "cmmi6" at 6.0pt
 -> cmmi6
Requested font "cmsy10" at 12.0pt
 -> cmsy10
Requested font "cmsy8" at 8.0pt
 -> cmsy8
Requested font "cmsy6" at 6.0pt
 -> cmsy6
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 7.
Requested font "cmr8" at 8.0pt
 -> cmr8
Requested font "cmr6" at 6.0pt
 -> cmr6
 [2])
\tf@toc=\write4
 [3]
```

Two things I noticed in the log, Joseph: first the Arabic Characters don't show here either, although they showed in the TexWorks log correctly.
Also, there is the msans font requested. I have no idea why it is requested. As a workaround, I will try to set the English font to the same font for Arabic and see what happens...

Comment: It might be useful to see the logs here: you should have a LaTeX `.log` and ` Biber `.blg` one. (I assume you ran XeLaTeX, Biber and XeLaTeX again.)

Comment: Does everything appear in the .bbl file? I have seen this before where it's just a problem with fonts - it's all fine but the PDF viewer just doesn't have the fonts to display the text.

Comment: PLK..The font I am using prints the Arabic Script in the document correctly into the pdf file. I think I have to use something in the bib file that says that I will use Arabic now... like in the document I use the polyglossia commands \textArabic{} and \begin{Arabic} to show the Arabic Script. But I have no idea how to do this in a multiscript bibliography

Comment: Joseph, yes I ran XeLateX, Biber and XeLateX again.

Comment: I will post the logs

Comment: I have updated the post with the logs

Comment: The script is interpreted as Latin script for the Polyglossia English language font..                                                       Missing character: There is no ط¨ in font [lmroman12-regular]:mapping=tex-text!

Comment: Does the .bbl file look ok? Also, there is a biber warning that the name has too many commas (more than two). Because bibtex name parsing libraries get really confused (crash ...) in such cases quite often, biber ignores such names. i suspect that this is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Arabic and biber but you may want to have a look at [`persian-bib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/persian-bib) package.

Comment: Mr. Vafa, I installed the package.. is there an English documentation for it?

Comment: No, but there is an example that you can try. If you need further help, you can contact Mahmood Amintoosi (the maintainer of that package). I am sure that if you ask him, he will write an English documentation for his package too.

Comment: I can't seem to find the example

Comment: biblatex-example.tex: http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/persian-bib/bibtex-example.tex

Comment: I have understood from the example that I have to use the package xpersian, but will I have to change the bib file?

Comment: And the bidi package clashes with polyglossia

Comment: No, bidi does not clash with polyglossia.

Comment: I can't get the xpersian package to work with my configuration and I can't reach Mahmood Amintoosi to get an English documentation...

Comment: I get ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package bidi.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.24 \edef
          \xepersianinfo{%

Comment: I loaded polyglossia before xepersian

Comment: I got it to compile now but the whole document is now from right to left and the references don't show up at all

Comment: @Laila: Please send me an email. <vafakhlg at googlemail.com>